# spark join fails with exception "ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$" but runs when pasting into spart-shell of Hadoop Cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to filter records from a file (facts) based on values from another file (list) using join.

```
case class CDR(no:Int,nm:String)
val facts = sc.textFile("/temp_scv/a.csv").map( (line) => { val cols = line.split(",");new CDR(cols(0).toInt,cols(1)); }).keyBy( (cdr:CDR) => cdr.no)
val list = sc.textFile("/temp_scv/b.csv").keyBy( (no) => no.toInt)
val filtered = facts.join(list)
```

When I package this as jar and execute this on `Hadoop cluster` using spark-submit it fails with exception

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$
```

However the same code runs fine when I paste it into spark-shell on the `Hadoop cluster`.

Comment: What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: Am using Spark 1.2.0

Comment: Thanks @Augusto it was version problem

Comment: With 1.6 I'm facing the same issue but I'm sure version is not the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a version mismatch. I am using Spark 1.2.0 on the clusters. And the code was compiled with sark-core version 1.3.0

Compiling the code with same spark-core version resolved the issue.